# Community blog?

Tags: discussion, community, site-promotion

We've now acquired a pretty solid group of 'avid users' of the site and I wanted to take a temperature check around the possibility people might be interested in contributing to a community blog, where we could do things that don't fit well on the mainpage for one reason or another:

- longer-form textual analysis
- biographies of philosophers
- reading philosophically-relevant literature or poetry
- discussing more general concerns about the practice of philosophy today (I'm thinking in particular things like discussing, in a measured way, sexual harassment issues in philosophy departments)

What do you think? Let's hear your feedback! We've got more than enough content-productive capacity to handle a blog post every now and then. Who would commit to be part of a committee around this?

--To be clear this is totally unofficial, and I do not think that it would be happening immediately, and furthermore there are other checkpoints I'd definitely like to ensure we're hitting before something like this happens (like a much more active chat, for one thing...)

Comment: Can we post a link to our blog to acid test to fellow members?

Comment: @Sniper Clown I guess so, though I'd be more curious about what you think of the proposal, what topics you think might be appropriate here, whether you'd be interested in committing your support, etc; note this wouldn't be a 'general-purpose' philosophy blog but ideally an extension of the work we're doing here

Comment: I would be definitely interested!